# What is typical new brake pad thickness?

Tags: brakes

2011 Nissan Murano, 71.000 miles : I pulled a front wheel and measured the thickness of the outboard brake pad - 1/4 in. of pad left. It has been awhile but as I remember new pads have about 1/2 in. of wear material. So in 71 K, I have only used half of the pads?  The rotor is smooth/flat with a couple thousandths of an OD lip. Are brakes that good today ? I am thinking I can go 100,000 miles on the original brakes ? In the "good old days" you were lucky to get one year or 20,000 miles from drum brake shoes , and needed to turn the drum.

Comment: Are these the rear pads?

Comment: I checked both front and rear.

Comment: I saw them at 83,000 when I got new tires ; couldn't see any change.

Comment: Now at 92,000  miles.

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems good so far - it also depends on the size of the discs - larger diameter also helps.

I had a fiat sedici (suzuki sx4) which ate pads and discs each year, now on my Jaguar I have had the same pads for 3 years and they are still fine.

before someone says different route etc I have the same route to work and same driving style...

Answer (score 0):

please do not edit my post mod im a certified master mechanic in real life i am speaking from real life experience thanks.

new pads have around 1/2" of material. if you slam the brakes a lot the pads will wear out real fast and youll get the wavy rotors... if you drive like you have a baby on board then they will last at least 50,000mi. on reddit one guy had over 120,000mi on originals but he drove a lot on the free way.

'now a days' if you get 20,000mi or less someones probably beating the brakes your car haha. disks are at least 4 times better than drums in my opinion. drum brakes on motorcycles are down right dangerous hahaha

Comment: The edit was not intended to slight your real-life reputation, but we do like to remain objective, formal and on point around here. Please review the [new user familiarization](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1460/675) for more information.

Comment: I'll read that asap, I wasnt taking it personally I just thought the last bit still had some merit i was just trying to give contrast to his "good old days" reference